# How to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k\sin(kx)$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation, closed-form

I tried to evaluate

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^n a^k\sin(kx)
> $$

using complex numbers but it didn't work... Any hint?

$a$ and $x$ are real numbers.

Comment: Hint: Let $z=a(\cos x+i \sin x)$. Then $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^k\sin (kx)=Im(\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k)=Im(\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z})$.

Comment: I'll add an answer when I have time, but I've been able to "simplify" it to the following (This uses no complex numbers)

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k\sin(kx) = \frac{a \left( \sin(x) - a^n\sin(nx + x) + a^{n+1}\sin(nx)\right)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}$$

I may have copied it wrong, but here's a graph that shows that it works: desmos.com/calculator/mbeid7e0jg

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. We assume $a, x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then one may write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \sin(k x)=\text{Im} \sum_{k=0}^n (ae^{ix})^k =\text{Im}\: \frac{1-(ae^{ix})^{n+1}}{1-ae^{ix}}
$$ where we have used the standard evaluation of a geometric sum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I obtained but I didn't manage to go further... Do you know if it's possible to simplify it "nicely"?

Comment: @Albert: How do you define "nicely" in this context?

Comment: @Albert If you multiply denominator and numerator by $1-ae^{-ix}$ you get $(1-ae^{ix})(1-ae^{-ix})=1+a^2+2a\cos x$ as the *new* denominator (maybe nicier?) and you can expand the *new* numerator then take $\text{Im}$.